# Why do some of the Batman: Animated Series episodes feature the Batman-Superman opening?

Tags: dc-animated-universe, batman-the-animated-series

I'm watching old episodes of Batman: The Animated Series on Amazon.com, and I notice several of them have, instead of the iconic B:TAS opening, an opening featuring Superman. Is there any difference in these episodes? Are they remastered or anything? Or is it just random choice on Amazon's part?

For example, on Amazon streaming, the pilot episode "On Leather Wings" had the opening featuring Superman, while the next episode, "Christmas with the Joker", had the one I expected. There were a few others with the opening featuring Superman as well, it seemed somewhat random.

ETA: This opening:

Vs this one:

ETA 2: "Fear of Victory" had yet another opening, featuring Robin. I give up. Amazon Prime is bizarre.

Comment: Sometimes when I've watched a "Law & Order" marathon on television, it has included "crossover" episodes from other series that continued the story arc.  Maybe the same thing's going on?

Comment: @WillFeldman No, these are B:TAS episodes, no Superman in them. I think they were rebranded later as a combo with S:TAS, but I have no idea if the content or quality changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opening title sequence with Superman is from *"The New Batman/Superman Adventures"* (TNBSA), and the classic Batman opening is from *"Batman: The Animated Series"* (BTAS).

Episodes for *"Batman: The Animated Series"* have been broadcast and distributed under both BTAS and TNBSA titles.  Other TNBSA episodes are sourced from *"Superman: The Animated Series"* and *"The New Batman Adventures"*; the final 24 episodes of BTAS, which used the animation style of the Superman show.

**Except for the opening title sequence, there is no observable difference between BTAS episodes sourced from either BTAS or TNBSA.**

The opening sequence used for your video stream depends on the release the episode was sourced from.  Streaming companies (Amazon, Netflix, Hulu, etc.) license different video releases.  If Amazon sourced a particular BTAS episode from a TNBSA release, then you will see the TNBSA opening.

Since streaming providers usually provide only a single access point to a given video stream, assuming your provider has access to both releases, I do not believe there is a way you can control whether the source of your BTAS episode is BTAS or TNBSA.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about [The New Batman/Superman Adventures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Batman_Superman_Adventures).

From Wikipedia

> The New Batman/Superman Adventures is a name given to a package series
>   that combined Superman: The Animated Series with The New Batman
>   Adventures produced by Warner Bros. Animation. It aired from 1997–2000
>   on Kids' WB. Each half-hour episode in the hour and one half block,
>   featured either a single repeat from the original Superman run, the
>   original Batman: The Animated Series, or a brand new story featuring
>   Batman made specifically for this series, drawn in an animation style
>   to match Superman: The Animated Series. These new stories focus more
>   on Batman's supporting cast and introduce new characters such as Tim
>   Drake. The two animated universes were united in the Superman episode
>   "World's Finest", which tells the story of Batman and Superman's first
>   meeting.

Comment: That's not what I was intending to watch, but that's definitely the opening sequence I saw. Curious!

Comment: Ankit's answer is absolutely right. I remember watching this hour long programming block as a kid. The used a different into for the block.

Comment: @MattD But why is it on the DVD like that? Or is it on the DVD like that? Maybe it's just Amazon?

Comment: I believe it's just Amazon. I own both series in their entirety on DVD, and they each use their own opening sequence as far as I can remember. It's been a while since I've watched them all, maybe 5 years, but to the best of my knowledge they use their respective openings. I know for a fact that the first season never had the opening with Superman ahead of any of the episodes, given you specifically reference "On Leather Wings". Further, new sets of the show have been released since I bought mine, and those could have the "alternate" opening on them.

Comment: I agree with MattD i have the collection too batman the animated series beginning goes like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A71i0a5x-qA) and superman the animated series opens like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUcKJflBG8Q)

Comment: @MattD If you make that an answer, and if you can vouch for there being otherwise no difference between episodes in terms of content or quality, I'll go ahead and accept, that's basically what I was after

Comment: I mean I can type up a more detailed answer later if that's what you want, they're two of my favorite cartoons and I cold wax epic on them all day, but in the end I feel I won't be adding much (in terms of relevancy) to what Ankit has already provided. Basically I'm not sure why some episodes on Amazon have the intro for The New Batman/Superman Adventures instead of the correct intro. That's more of a technical error, but Ankit provides an answer for why that alternate intro even exists.

Answer (score -1):

The different opening sequences are because the episodes are presented in collections instead of seasons, making each collection a mashup of different seasons/series.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: What does it adds to the existing answers?